# Mac application receipt refresh fails in the Sandbox environment

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase

I have to add renewable IAP to a mac application and I have to provide a restore mechanism also.
I have researched existing threads but couldn't find any similar cases.

The application receipt contains all the purchases the user made with his/er ... so whenever the user makes a purchase I have to send the application receipt to my server for validation. This seems reasonable since at the moment the user makes a purchase he/she is logged in the Mac App Store and the application receipt should be up to date.

When I want to restore the users purchases I can see 2 options:

1. Before 10.9 you can call the restoreCompletedTransactions method on the SKPaymentQueue and handle all the restored transactions. But these transactions don't have the transactionReceipt from the iOS ... so with every restore I would just send the application receipt to my server for validation. I checked after restoring the transactions the application receipt is updated.
2. From 10.9 there is a new request to refresh the application receipt and that can be used to restore transactions: SKReceiptRefreshRequest. This way the restore would have only 2 steps: refreshing the receipt and sending it only once to my server for validation.

My problem is that in the sandbox environment I cannot use the SKReceiptRefreshRequest, every time I use it I get this message: ["Applicationame" is damaged and can't be opened. Delete "Applicationame" and download it again from the App Store.] I tried to logout of the Mac Store, restart the storeagent, restart my computer, specify receiptProperties for the request ... but nothing helped ...

Note: If the app is running and I delete the receipt manually and then try to refresh the receipt the receipt refresh works fine and the receipt is downloaded. But the next time I start the app and try a receipt refresh while having the previous receipt in place the same error appears.

Did anybody see this issue before? If yes did you find a solution?

Thanks!
Aliz

Comment: Same problem here.

I am surprised to see only your question on this issue. Maybe this is a sandbox issue that is new in 10.9.2?

Comment: Since the 10.9.2 update had an important fix I think most people proceeded with the upgrade ... so I have no old system with the earlier version. If anybody has one and could make a check that would be helpful .... If I cannot get this working I will not release my app without testing it through in sandbox ... so I might have to to send the app receipt for every restored transaction ...

Comment: The issue happens as well in the production environment, tested with 10.9.2

Comment: Has it been solved? I have the same issue!

Comment: Same issue here on 10.9.3.

Comment: Still the same issue. I ended up submitting my app to the AppStore with the pre 10.9 solution, sending the same app receipt for every restored transaction... at least this works.

Comment: I'm on 10.9.3, and it's working fine here with RMStore, after necessary Mac adjustments. Link here: https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore

Comment: What do you mean by necessary Mac adjustments? I just checked again and I still get the error. These are my steps, please correct me if you see any issues: 
1. start a freshly created build outside of xCode so the receipt is generated correctly.
2. I start the receipt refresh request the same way it is started in your library
3. I get the build is damaged message.

Comment: Just bumped into this one. OSX 10.10.3 here - "Damage report" after the first (clean and successful) refresh request. Any progress on the issue? Does it create problems "in real life"?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with SKReceiptRefreshRequest, even on shipping apps. Insanely frustrating. It just seems to be completely broken. I've also verified that if a receipt already exists (and it always will in my case because I'm checking for that on launch) then the "app is damaged" alert will always be shown. If I launch the app and then (while it is running) trash the receipt folder, before calling the refresh request, then it completes as expected.

Comment: Any news about That? I have the very same problem. Also I always get the the error no matter if I create a empty receipt file or if the receipt file do not exists.